# Unibody MacBook WiFi Drivers for Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, wireless-networking, macbook, boot-camp

I have a Unibody MacBook Pro running Windows 7 x64 on Boot camp (with the Snow Leopard boot camp update applied)

It's been having trouble connecting to certain WiFi networks, and I'd like to update the WiFi drivers.

Where can I find updated drivers for it (preferably with support for Windows 7's virtual WiFi)?  Update Driver in Device Manager doesn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boot Camp 3.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL979), released three days ago, includes newer WiFi drivers with support for Windows 7's new Virtual WiFi feature.

Answer (score 0):

just try the bootcamp 3.1 update, I'm downloading it right now and my Windows 7 wifi hasn't been working hopefully this will work